# How to add a entry in history API when page open?

Tags: javascript

I need add a entry in History to close a modal when I click on back button.

```js
function addHistory() {
    window.history.pushState("forward", null, "");
}
```

When I use a click button to call the function, it works, but when I call the function on page load, the entry doesn't work when page back.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  window.history.pushState("forward", null, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `window.history.pushState()` might not work as expected in `window.onload` is due to the timing. When the `load` event is fired, the page and all the resources are already loaded. If you try to push a state at that time, it might not function as you'd expect because the browser has already completed its initial history setup for the page.

Instead of using the `load` event, you can use the `DOMContentLoaded` event. It fires as soon as the DOM (all the HTML) is fully loaded and parsed, but before any resources like images and stylesheets are finished loading.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    window.history.pushState('forward', null, ''); 
});
```